# Error trying to protect website with a password

Tags: php, html, css, http

I'm trying to setup a directory on my website with a password and I keep getting Internal Server Error:

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request....

What could be the cause?

I have all my files in folder named "PasswordProtected". In this folder I have file .htaccess :

```
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "restricted area"  
AuthUserFile /main/PasswordProtected/.htpasswd  
require valid-user
```

and I also have file .htpasswd :

```
user:isFu5zSvpK5Xg
```

When it type url `http://domain.com/main/PasswordProtected/index.html` on the browser
I do get prompted to enter user name and password but then I get the error message.

Am I doing something wrong in here?

All I need is a one user one password setup to demo the site

I'll appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Comment: How did you create the .htpasswd file? Is `isFu5zSvpK5Xg`  your literal password?

Comment: it is supposed to be encripted.. I created it with a password generator.

Comment: That should be OK then. Is `/main/PasswordProtected/.htpasswd` the full system path to the file?

Comment: make sure you have the modules enabled for it and use the proper command to make that file.  `htpasswd -c filename username` and it will prompt for pwd.  Ref: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_file.html

Comment: @Pekka I uploaded main folder to the root of my 1&1 sever, so I believe that is the right path. I also tried path domain.com/main/PasswordProtected/.htpasswd without success

Comment: Nope, the full path is likely to be much longer (you can provoke the system into showing it by adding garbage like `<? xyzddsfasadfs ?>` into a .php file. The resulting error message will tell you where the file is located. But try using just `.htpasswd` first, with no path

Comment: @Pekka. wait. so I'm triying to protect a simple html file. Should this be a php file instead. I not so familiar with this stuff.

Comment: No, the PHP thing was just a workaround to find the full filesystem path. It's unlikely to be necessary, though: just remove the path so the line says `AuthUserFile .htpasswd`. That should work as long as the htpasswd file is in the directory that is being protected

Comment: @Pekka still not working. Just to make sure.. So, besides adding files .htpasswd and .htaccess to the protected directory, Am I supposed to add code elsewhere? Is there anything I need to do to the protected files of directory? Thank you!

Comment: Read this, it might help... http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/htaccess-101/

Comment: If you click cancel when prompted to enter the password, do you get an access denied / authorization required message rather than an internal error message?